# Form submission: PHP S_SESSION statements within a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session, foreach

Let's suppose I have the following PHP code which attempts to read from an array called `$arr` which takes on the values *{fullname, studentnumber, email}*. Upon submission of my HTML form, this PHP code will execute the foreach loop, and store the values posted to the page in the `$_SESSION` array.

```
foreach($arr as $field):
    $_SESSION[$field] = $_POST[$field];
endforeach;
```

The above code doesn't work as intended. If I were to replace the above code block with the code below, the values in the fields on my page get stored correctly in the `$_SESSION` array.

```
$_SESSION[fullname] = $_POST[fullname];
$_SESSION[studentnumber] = $_POST[studentnumber];
$_SESSION[email] = $_POST[email];
```

How do I accomplish this, in an efficient and expandable way? I don't want to have to write new $_SESSION statements every time I add a new field to my form.

EDIT: // The first block of code actually works as intended. There was a typo originally!

Comment: What you have _should_ work, provided `$arr` is populated as an array `$arr = array('fullname','studentnumber','email')`

Comment: Given that you have unquoted array keys, we must assume you don't have error reporting turned on so there might be some other issue earlier in your code.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you will see a pile of notices about the use of undefined constants..  Those array keys should be quoted like `$_SESSION['fullname']`

Comment: Stupid me. There's a typo in $POST; it should be $_POST! Can't believe I overlooked that one. Thanks Michael and @asifrc for your replies. Sorry for bothering you both with triviality.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to use array_keys() otherwise you're getting the array contents.

```
foreach (array_keys($arr) as $field)
```

Let me know if this works/is what you're looking for :)

Comment: what I'm looking for is to use the actual names of the field elements in my page, and not increments. In the second block of code, I'm using the variables _fullname_, _studentnumber_, and _email_. I want these values to be grabbed from the `$_POST`, and inserted into the `$_SESSION` array in the foreach loop, as per their field names.

Comment: Actually, my code should be `foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $field)`, but if you're using $arr, then that is safer. Have you followed @michael's suggestion of adding the quotes? My first guess would be that..